# Remove tuples from a list

Tags: python, list

I have the two lists below:

```
list1 = [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, '?'), (4, 'T'), (5, 'A'), (6, 'B'), (7, '?'), (8, 'T')]
list2 = [(2, 'D'), (6, 'E'), (7, '!'), (10, 'T')]
```

I need to remove from `list1` the elements in common with `list2` that are in first position. So, I've used the for loop below:

```
for x in list1:
    id_list1 = x[0]

    for y in list2:
        id_list2 = y[0]

        if id_list1 == id_list2:
            list1.remove(x)
```

The output is: `[(1, 'A'), (3, '?'), (4, 'T'), (5, 'A'), (7, '?'), (8, 'T')]`

The result is strange because I see `(7, '?')` in `list1` but not `(2, 'B')` and `(6, 'B')`. The last two tuples are correctly removed, but why not `(7, '?')`?

The expected output is: `[(1, 'A'), (3, '?'), (4, 'T'), (5, 'A'), (8, 'T')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
list1 = [(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "?"), (4, "T"), (5, "A"), (6, "B"), (7, "?"), (8, "T")]
list2 = [(2, "D"), (6, "E"), (7, "!"), (10, "T")]

first_items = set(i for i, _ in list2)
list1[:] = [item for item in list1 if item[0] not in first_items]
print(list1)
```

output:

```
[(1, 'A'), (3, '?'), (4, 'T'), (5, 'A'), (8, 'T')]
```

Basically you create a set from first items of the `list2`, then with a list comprehension you pick items from `list1` whose first items are not appear in that list. `list1[:]` does the job in-place.

Set is chosen because of O(1) membership testing. You could use list or tuple if you're dealing with small lists.

But why your own solution doesn't work:
You shouldn't remove something from a list [while you're iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/13944524):

To fix it, change `for x in list1` to `for x in list1[:]`. Now you're iterating over *a copy* of that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
list1 = [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, '?'), (4, 'T'), (5, 'A'), (6, 'B'), (7, '?'), (8, 'T')]
list2 = [(2, 'D'), (6, 'E'), (7, '!'), (10, 'T')]
for x in list1[:]:
    id_list1 = x[0]

    for y in list2:
        id_list2 = y[0]

        if id_list1 == id_list2:
            list1.remove(x)
print(list1)
```

the reason for the weird behaviour is because when u remove an element from list1,
elemensts shift to the left so i might skip an ele.